# How to create dynamic images with struts2?

Tags: struts2

In strut2, the `<s:img>` tag is gone. How can I create dynamic images?

**Update**

I want to set the image 'src' according to a parameter in the value stack (like ${userName_}).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a search on the struts2's offical website and found they doesn't provide a dynamic image tag. There is a struts2 image plug which provide this, however it is in alpha stage.
http://code.google.com/p/s2-image/. At last, I had to do this in pure JSP codes.

**Update**
Gashhh...There is another simple way by using `<img src=<s:text name="genTP" /> />`. But I think is quite strange.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a specific tag. You just use the plain html tag `<img src="...">` , the `src` attribute pointing to the static/dynamic url that gives you the image.

Now, if the url points to an action in your same Struts2 webapp, you'll want to code an action that returns a dynamic image instead of a html page. In that case, you should read about the [Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html)... if you can find anything useful in the official page/wiki (sigh... the docs are messed out at this moment, do yourself a favour and buy "Struts2 in Action"). The concept is quite clean  once you grasp it. See for example:

http://www.javahowto.net/struts2/dynamic-mime-type-on-stream-result-struts-2/