# How to change jquerytheme with struts2 using a properties file

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, properties-file

This is somewhat related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758121/struts2-display-image-get-image-url-from-a-properties-file) in which I was able to display an image getting its URL from a properties file in this way:

```
<img height="40" src="<s:text name="login.logo"/>" class="pagelogo" alt="Logo" /> Login
```

And using the same way I was able to edit certain `style` / CSS properties:

```
<h2 class="ccsBlockTitle" style="background-color: <s:text name="welcome.color" />">Welcome<h2>
```

Where my `content.properties` looks like this one:

```
login.logo=/oneFolderBefore/resources/media/login.png
login.title=Login
welcome.color=red
gui.theme=blitzer
```

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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)'s a list of the available themes and [how to use them](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki#support-for-themes)

However when calling it in this way:

```
<sj:head locale="es" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="<s:text name="gui.theme"/>" compressed="false" defaultIndicator="ajax_loading" />
```

I would expect the above code to be "reduced" / "translated" to:

```
<sj:head locale="es" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="blitzer" compressed="false" defaultIndicator="ajax_loading" />
```

However what I'm getting is an error like this one:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/decorators/PlantillaWeb.jsp (line: [37], column: [73]) equal symbol expected
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:372)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:276)
    com.seguritech.botones.plugin.interceptor.ValidarSesionInterceptor.intercept(ValidarSesionInterceptor.java:51)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CookieProviderInterceptor.intercept(CookieProviderInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CookieInterceptor.intercept(CookieInterceptor.java:258)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CookieInterceptor.intercept(CookieInterceptor.java:258)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:575)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

Where line 37 is the above posted and col 73 is between `me` in `gui.theme`.

So, I thought in changing the inner double quotes for single quotes:

```
<sj:head locale="es" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="<s:text name='gui.theme'/>" compressed="false" defaultIndicator="ajax_loading" />
```

But then when I inspect my HTML I get this:

```
<link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-project/struts/themes/<s:text name='gui.theme'/>/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.7.1" type="text/css">
```

And if I change the outer ones like this:

```
<sj:head locale="es" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme='<s:text name="gui.theme"/>' compressed="false" defaultIndicator="ajax_loading" />
```

I get this:

```
<link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-project/struts/themes/<s:text name=" gui.theme"="">
```

I also tried changing the value for `jquerytheme` for `${gui.theme}` but I got the same error as in my previous question which says:

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

So, what could be another way for changing the `jquerytheme` property value retrieving it from my `content.properties` file?

In the cases above except the first one (using double double-quotes) I was getting the default `base` theme.

Comment: Struts tags syntax doesn't allow you to use EL expressions.

Comment: @RomanC yes, that's what I found out in my previous question as well... and that's the reason I didn't taken into account at first when I tried using the `s:text name` try first, but when I couldn't I decided to try using a EL expression just to try some luck. However I've searched all ways I could think of and can't find something similar. Do you know any way to do what I want? Any workaround maybe, anything could be of help

Comment: You can load properties in many ways, then apply it to the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended leaving this line as is:

```
<sj:head locale="es" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="base" compressed="false" defaultIndicator="ajax_loading" />
```

Later on I thought in "concatenating" strings after reading this blog: [JQuery UI: Change theme dynamically using a drop-down](http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=2006) where they have the following code:

```
<head> 
  <link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
...
<select id="themes">
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">Le Frog</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">Start</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">Smoothness</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">Redmond</option>
  <option value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">Sunny</option>
</select>  
...
```

That gave me the idea of having this line after the one I posted before:

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">
```

divided in 3 parts in my `content.properties` file like this:

```
gui.current.theme=south-street

gui.theme.url.part1=//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/
gui.theme.url.part2=/jquery-ui.css
```

And the above line divided like this:

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="<s:text name="gui.theme.url.part1" /><s:text name="gui.current.theme" /><s:text name="gui.theme.url.part2" />" />
```

With these changes I was able to do what I wanted and now my theme changes its CSS styles according to whatever theme (included in the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) page) I write in the `gui.current.theme` property.